# How can I binding data to paypal-rest-sdk

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

When I use the same json object in the sample everything is ok but when I try to put my data like req.body.totalPrice, for example, I got an error.

```
var create_payment_json = {
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
},
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://return.url",
    "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
},
"transactions": [{
    "item_list": {
        "items": [{
            "name": "item",
            "sku": "item",
            "price": "1.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 1
        }]
    },
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": req.body.totalPrice // return error
    },
    "description": "This is the payment description."
}]
};
```

Comment: Does req.body.totalPrice need to be a string?

Comment: No. I try let price = req.body.totalPrice.toString() then "total": price and dosn't work too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the items price and amount price should be the same otherwise you will a 400 error